# How to launch WhatsApp in flutter web or launch WhatsApp from browser?

Tags: flutter, whatsapp, flutter-web, whatsapi

How to launch WhatsApp in **Flutter web** or launch WhatsApp from **browser** in Flutter or suggest any package from pub.dev?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give an anchor with href to `https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=(phone_number)`

For full code

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=6281144441111&text=Hello">Send Hi to me</a>
```

**Note:**
Make sure you give your country code without (+).
for example 6281144441111

Answer (score 0):

You need the url_launcher https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher. Import the package in you're yaml and then in your .dart

Then use the launch function with the WhatsApp URL: `launch('whatsapp://send?phone=$phonenumber')`

For the launching the WhatsApp Website use `launch('https://web.whatsapp.com')`